# Wifi issues Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireless

I have been having wifi issues since I installed Linux a few months back but since I was always using an ethernet cable, I didn't bother too much with it. But now, I don't have access to an ethernet cable.

My wifi card does not connect and keeps telling me "activation of network connection failed"

I bought a USB wifi dongle. Now this was working for a while and stopped working for idk what reason. Now, it kept asking me for the password repeatedly.

I reinstalled Ubuntu today and the issues are still there. I've been using usb tethering from my phone for now as a short-term solution. Any help?

```
  **sudo lshw -C network**

   *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 05
       serial: e0:db:55:e3:1f:d8
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c1404000-c1404fff memory:c1400000-c1403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlp8s0f0
       version: 00
       serial: fc:4d:d4:51:c3:48
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt76x0e driverversion=5.0.0-25-generic firmware=1.0.07-b370 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:c1500000-c15fffff
  *-network:0
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:1
       logical name: wlx78321b9197f1
       serial: 78:32:1b:91:97:f1
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: enp0s20u3
       serial: 92:03:7d:73:a9:9f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.215 link=yes multicast=yes

**rfkill list all**

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I'm at my wits end. I've tried many solutions listed online but none of them worked. I hope this can be fixed

Comment: maybe this one helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062390/activation-of-network-connection-failed-for-ethernet-connection

Comment: See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2354328&p=13614520&#post13614520

Comment: @AlexOnLinux Fast startup is already disabled. Perhaps, I need to get rid of my dual boot but I need Windows for some of my work.

Comment: @Jeremy31 I tried the solution in the link you sent. No luck :(