# “Activation of network connection failed” for wifi connection version 20.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, 20.04, internet

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Asus laptop with dual boot along side Windows 10, and I can get the wifi connection when i restart my laptop but after 2/3  minutes automatically wifi icon disappeared and i get a error "activation of network connection failed" then if i goto wifi section under setting then i can see wifi is on but there is no wifi signal showed in the visible wifi section and it also shows "Unavailable" under the heading text "Wifi". In the mean time if i switch to windows 10 in same laptop then i can see the wifi running on windows 10 very smoothly. I have tried every common solution on internet but none of those works at all even i have reinstalled ubuntu 3 times but its didn't work. Is there anyone in the world who can solve this? Btw I'm a junior dev and this is kind of sad that i feels like this is the worse OS/Distro that has no solution for a simple problem.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue. By disabling my Wi-Fi IPv6, it's working fine now.

1. At first you need to go to computer's Wi-Fi settings then go to the Wi-Fi profile that you want to connect.

   [image]
2. Click IPv6 tab and disable the IPv6 and click apply to save.

   [image]
3. Finally toggle the system Wi-Fi button to restart your Wi-Fi adapter.

   [image]

Comment: Where did these screen shots come from?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I changed the driver for wi-fi by going into Software & Updates->Additional Drivers, and then changing the driver in Additional Drivers. This option to change will be automatically suggested.
In my case the wireless network adaptor is Realtek Network Adaptor.

Comment: Hello. You have not offered an answer you have asked a question. Not what answers are for.

Comment: @David I have changed the answer now!

Comment: @Habib 080 
Did your issue get resolved? If so, was it by this method or some other method?

Comment: @David which screenshots?