# Activation of Network Connection Failed in UBUNTU 23.04

Tags: networking

I've dual boot system in my laptop. Windows 10 and Ubuntu 23.04.My Wi-Fi average speed is 1 MB/s. It continues working smoothly on Windows 10. But I'm facing problem in Ubuntu. After a few minutes, a message says that "***Activation of Network Connection Failed"*** Then I've to reconnect but the problem repeats. I've read these posts and tried the solution[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323075/activation-of-network-connection-failed-for-wifi-connection-version-20-04) But it did not work in my case. I have A Realtech Wi-Fi adapter.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Is this a new issue, or have these dropped connections been happening since you installed the Ubuntu OS? If the former, did you recently upgrade or update the OS?

Comment: I face the problem when I run UBUNTU after using WINDOWS 10 for a while.