# Previously good WiFi fails to connect

Tags: networking, wireless, router

My Sony Vaio (Ubuntu  22.04.3) has worked with my BT Hub for years, but it's now displaying 'Activation of network connection failed' and will not connect. The computer sees the network and attempts the connection, but never succeeds. The password is correct and other devices still connect to the BT Hub. The computer did connect to a phone hotspot. Any ideas of what to check would be welcome.

Comment: What is a BT hub? Bathtub? Bluetooth?  Bahama Telecom?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“Activation of network connection failed” for wifi connection version 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323075/activation-of-network-connection-failed-for-wifi-connection-version-20-04)

Comment: Could be IPv6 related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323075/activation-of-network-connection-failed-for-wifi-connection-version-20-04

Comment: Fixed it by turning the broadband hub off and on and restarting the computer.  No idea why only one device was locked out.   Also, please don't edit my grammar which was better than the amended version.