# Both Ethernet and Wi-Fi not working on Ubuntu 20.04 after recent update

Tags: drivers, 20.04, wireless, kernel, ethernet

I recently performed an update on my workstation using Ubuntu 20.04. Neither the Wi-Fi LAN card (I am using iptime N150UA) nor ethernet connection is working, and both seem to be not detected as shown in the screenshot. I checked the LAN card and ethernet cable is properly functioning on other computers, and the ethernet light is turned on green when the cable is connected to the workstation as well.

[Screenshot of network settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n1E3.png)

Some logs for troubleshooting I tried are as follows:

```
~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:92104000-92104fff memory:92100000-92103fff
```

```
~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
~$ uname -r
5.15.0-1048-oracle
```

```
~$ lspci -nn | grep 0200
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
```

```
~$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Nov 27 12:22:18 thunder-desktop dbus-daemon[1376]: [session uid=1000 pid=1376] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.92' (uid=1000 pid=2375 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real " label="unconfined")
Nov 27 12:22:18 thunder-desktop systemd[1364]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Nov 27 12:22:19 thunder-desktop dbus-daemon[1376]: [session uid=1000 pid=1376] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Nov 27 12:22:19 thunder-desktop systemd[1364]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Nov 27 12:22:19 thunder-desktop systemd[1364]: Started VTE child process 2389 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 2378.
Nov 27 12:22:19 thunder-desktop systemd[1364]: gnome-launched-x-terminal-emulator-2372.scope: Succeeded.
Nov 27 12:22:20 thunder-desktop dbus-daemon[1376]: [session uid=1000 pid=1376] Activating service name='org.gnome.gedit' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1000 pid=1631 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Nov 27 12:22:20 thunder-desktop dbus-daemon[1376]: [session uid=1000 pid=1376] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.gedit'
Nov 27 12:22:21 thunder-desktop gnome-shell[1631]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x20000f8
Nov 27 12:22:51 thunder-desktop gsd-color[1777]: unable to get EDID for xrandr-default: unable to get EDID for output
```

```
~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1401
```

I checked similar questions and answers (e.g., https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/updated-system-all-networking-lost-following-reboot-4175690186/#post6218320) which suggest that there may be an issue with the grub bootloader. Though the configuration file which should be in /etc/default/grub does not exist. Cool start of performing shutdown and then starting did not work for me as well suggested in [Wired connection stopped working after update (Realtek Ethernet) - Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342090/wired-connection-stopped-working-after-update-realtek-ethernet-ubuntu-20-04/1342203#1342203)

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The -oracle kernel is intended for use in Oracle Cloud services. Try a real hardware kernel.